# Apache preferred DocumentRoot path

Tags: php, apache, apache2, directory, document-root

I'm wondering is there a difference of having my site within the `/var/www` or `/home/myuser/public/sites`. Just seen some tutorials that points to the former then others to the latter, but didn't mentioned some key benefits of having it placed there. If you know some articles that explains this best please share it with me.

Huge thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference that I can think of from one directory to another is if it's on a separate partition and you set different flags, such as `noexec` or `nosuid`. Apart from that, the actual directory you use doesn't matter.

However, with that said, by default a user's home directory is created within `/home`, so especially in something like a shared hosting server, it makes sense to have the `DocumentRoot` as a sub-directory of the user's home directory, which allows them to easily modify the files without having to worry about them needing give them permissions to leave their home directory, and thus making it easy to "lock" them in by things such as FTP or SFTP with chroot.

Comment: Great explanation. Just to build on it a little... I prefer to have the docroot in my home directory on my dev machines, but on my servers I prefer to have it in /var/www. That way it's slightly easier to get to locally, and I don't have to share anything in my home directory with other developers on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are no pros or cons sir. You have the freedom to use what you want to.